# c# vb: Should we use System.Lazy for resource-intensive task? (when threading is not needed)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance

I'm wondering is there some kind of JIT-hack going on with System.Lazy to make things more performant or is it purely a "normal class"?

From the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx it says:

> Use an instance of Lazy(Of T) to defer
>   the creation of a large or
>   resource-intensive object or the
>   execution of a resource-intensive
>   task, particularly when such creation
>   or execution might not occur during
>   the lifetime of the program.

but i can defer the execution of a resource-intensive task using a simple boolean flag couldn't i? So what exactly is the difference? (other than System.Lazy has additional overheads for no apparent "syntax sugar" gains)

With a simple boolean flag its simply:

```
if (!deferred) {
    //run resource-intensive task
}
```

Edit:

here's an example

```
class Human{
    System.Lazy<String> name = new System.Lazy<String>(() =>
    {
        //code here takes 4 seconds to run
        return "the value";
    });
    String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

vs

```
class Human
{
    String name;
    bool name_initiated;
    String Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (!name_initiated)
            {
                //code here takes 4 seconds to run
                name = "the value";
                name_initiated = true;
            }
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

6 May: now i use this alot. And i really mean alot alot. i use it whenever i need to cache data (even when the computation is 0.1 second or lesser). Hence my question, should i be worried? Now i know you will tell me to profile the app, but im building the library first before i build the app and by that time if the app has problems that would mean Major change

Comment: Can you show techique how to defer loading/execution with simple boolean flag? You can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_need

Comment: I'll let someone less lazy formulate an answer... Oh by the way F# uses `Lazy<T>` and provides a bit of syntax sugar. `let ls = lazy([1;2;3])`

Comment: @Nick i've edited the question to show how to defer loading/execution with a simple boolean flag.

Comment: @Nick.. the link justifies the use of lazy evaluation which im not arguing about. but it doesn't justify the use of System.Lazy which is why im saying we can achieve lazy evaluation with a simple boolean flag why use System.Lazy?

Comment: @Pacerier, but how it is deferred there? How computation triggered? And what is semantics for this flag? Do task whether deffered or eager? Anyway, Jon Skeet already placed a nice answer. Take a look. If you wonder why it ever exists take a look to another article how to implement singleton pattern: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html it also can be done via simple boolean flag ;)

Comment: @Nick sorry i guess I've not been clear on my question. I've edited my question to: should we use System.Lazy for resource-intensive task (when threading is not required)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could defer it with a simple Boolean flag. Of course, you'd need to handle volatility of both the flag and the result... and make sure you knew what you wanted in terms of the result if one thread asks for the result while it's still being computed. Oh, and try to avoid locking where possible. And make it all bulletproof in terms of thread safety.

Nah, no benefit at all to using a type built by experts ;)

Seriously: why do it yourself if someone else has done it for you? Why write the code to check a flag, work out how to wait safely, lock everything etc. Even if it *were* a relatively simple thing to get right, it's better if it only needs to be done *once* in a reusable fashion.

Another good example of this principle is `Nullable<T>`. You could easily get *most* of the same behaviour yourself (not boxing) or even not bother with the encapsulation at all, and just keep a flag alongside your normal field... but with the built-in type, you get all of that implemented for free, along with syntactic sugar etc.

Comment: @Jon, you have nice acticle about singleton implementation http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx, you can link it here since singleton can be "implemented" via simple boolean flag too. But its offtopic a bit of course.

Comment: @Nick: Well, you can implement the singleton pattern with `Lazy<T>`, but it's not the same thing really... I think I'd prefer not to muddy the waters within my answer, but the link's in the comments now anyway :)

Comment: @Jon, I just want to show: things can be more complex than it looks in overview. Singleton (and your article and book) are nice demo on this. Of course, I don't think `Lazy<T>` same thing with singleton pattern :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet sorry i guess I've not been clear on my question. I've edited my question to: should we use System.Lazy for resource-intensive task (when threading is not required)

Comment: @Pacerier: The context of your question still isn't clear. If you can show us a *complete* sample, we can say whether `Lazy<T>` would be useful. It's a way of representing a value to be computed when it's first needed, which can then be used repeatedly. If you're not in that situation, it's not useful.

Comment: @Pacerier: Then I think it becomes like the nullable case - yes, you can do it yourself, but I think I'd just use `Lazy<T>` for simplicity.

Comment: @Jon Skeet now i use this alot. And i really mean alot alot. i use it whenever i need to cache data (even when the computation is 0.1 second or lesser). Hence my question, should i be worried? Now i know you will tell me to profile the app, but im building the library first before i build the app and by that time if the app has problems that would mean Major change

Answer (score 2):

The Lazy class makes the process easier. It is similar to using a String instead of a character array. Not technically necessary, but can be useful.

Comment: `String` actually does provide a number of CLR-level optimizations that you couldn't implement outside of the runtime using a simple `char[]`.

Comment: @dahlbyk: In either case, the main point of using `String` is the semantic simplicity. You could do interning yourself if you wanted, not in exactly the same way, but you could get the vast majority of the performance if you knew what you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

`Lazy<T>` is just an encapsulation of the best way to implement a lazy singleton. If you want thread-safety, there's more to it than just `if(!initialized) instance = Initialize();`. I generally assume the BCL team will be better at implementing than me.

**Update:** Based on your sample, I would say the advantage of `Lazy<>` is simply less code to maintain. Beyond that, they're essentially equivalent. My advice: use `Lazy<>` because it's easy and move on to harder problems.

Comment: sorry i guess I've not been clear on my question. I've edited my question to: should we use System.Lazy for resource-intensive task (when threading is not required)

Answer (score 1):

The Lazy class does all the thread-safety work for you, which is the sort of thing that is a lot more complicated than it sounds to implement by hand.

Comment: sorry i guess I've not been clear on my question. I've edited my question to: should we use System.Lazy for resource-intensive task (when threading is not required)